# webkit-transition for "top" and "bottom" properties

Tags: css, animation, webkit

I'd like to make a css animation where a div (centered on a screen using *top* and *bottom* properties) expands by setting *top* and *bottom* to 20px.

Is it possible? When I try to make it happen with:

> ```
> -webkit-transition-property: top, bottom;
> -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
> ```

animation is not performed. Am I doing something wrong, or is it not supposed to work with these properties?

P.S. I'm doing this for a Titanium desktop application, so only webkit matters...

Comment: Can we see some more code? Maybe you're assigning the CSS to the wrong selector.

Comment: Sorry, my wrong! I've overseen that the first class sets top and bottom properties in %, and the second in px... With the same measurements it works ok...

Comment: Had the same problem. In my case, first state didn't have any top rule and the second state had top rule. Adding top:0px to the first state solved the problem.

Answer (score 16):

Here is a example code that works on safari 5 :

```css
#test{
  background:#3F3;
  position: absolute;
  top:50px;
  bottom:50px;
  width:200px;
  -webkit-transition-property: top, bottom;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
#test:hover {
  top:100px;
  bottom:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: You may want to add a CSS elastic easing transition http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23462515/elastic-easing-in-css3-best-approach

Answer (score 7):

Here's some code that works on Chrome v31:

```
-webkit-transition: top 0.5s, bottom 0.5s;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        #test {
            background:#3F3;
            position: absolute;
            top:50px;
            bottom:50px;
            width:200px;
            -webkit-transition-property: top, bottom;
            -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
        }
        #test:hover {
            top:100px;
            bottom:100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test">Ganesh
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```