# Transform CSS 'top' in Chrome?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, transform

I am trying to run a transform animation in CSS on the 'top' property, but it's not working in Chrome resulting in a poor transition as apposed to a smooth animation in something like chrome.

Take this Code Pen for example: http://codepen.io/esassaman/pen/wrsvx

```
    .navbar-toggle .icon-bar:nth-of-type(2) {
        top: 1px;
    }

    .navbar-toggle .icon-bar:nth-of-type(3) {
        top: 2px;
    }

    .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
        position: relative;
        transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    }

    .navbar-toggle.active .icon-bar:nth-of-type(1) {
        top: 6px;
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }

    .navbar-toggle.active .icon-bar:nth-of-type(2) {
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    .navbar-toggle.active .icon-bar:nth-of-type(3) {
        top: -6px;
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Are you looking something like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3053846/4584849

or like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/20529657/4584849

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're trying to achieve. Nothing happens in Chrome, Firefox or IE. Could you please add images of what you would like to happen?

Comment: In the CodePen example, reduce your browser width so that the button appears (it's mobile only in this example) ..click the toggle button.. in Chrome, the 'top' CSS property is not animated, so it jumps.. in other browsers, such as Safari, it is animated so it is a smooth animation.

Answer (score 0):

I see, but in `Chrome 43.0.2357.130 m` working well. It's a smooth animation, no problems

Comment: Yes it works on mobile but not on desktop... i'll be wanting a similar button on desktop.

Comment: Ok but I have this animation on my desktop (by resizing the page), on my smartphone and my notebook (resizing too) and everything is working on chrome. I can took u a screenshots :)
In Mozilla on desktop working too.

Comment: The animation works but if you look closely you will definitely see a 'jump' as the top: 6px fails to animate, so it just jumps from 1px to 6px, the rest of the animation works fine, this is definitely a Chrome problem as Chrome (desktop) does not animate 'top'